# Metamask cannot recognize the token address

Tags: solidity, blockchain, erc-20, bsc

I forked a Dividend paying token from a current popular project and deployed it on BSC testnet for a test purpose.

Everything works fine and it shows on BSC test net without any problem. I also try several transfer transactions using truffle console and it works fine.

However, I am not able to add it to my metamask wallet. I am not sure where it goes wrong.

If anybody have idea please share to me, it will be appreciated.

The deployed contract address is listed below FYI (on BSC testnet)

0x2f7dafc9a7282939dfbe6d950aa9ca97ed1aebbb https://testnet.bscscan.com/token/0x2f7dafc9a7282939dfbe6d950aa9ca97ed1aebbb

##### Environment

I deployed this contract by Truffle env below:
Truffle v5.2.6 (core: 5.2.6)
Node v12.22.1
The solidity compiler is 0.6.12 as below:

```
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.6.12",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
    },
  },
  solc: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 200
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

FIXED:

I was thinking would it be the issue of the BSC testnet end point, so that I changed the endpoint to other spare one: https://data-seed-prebsc-2-s3.binance.org:8545
And it is working fine now.
I think the end of of first BSC test net is down.